# How to hard code credentials in a PHP process to avoid the user from getting prompts for username/password when they are forwarded

Tags: php, ldap

Hello – I am looking to create a PHP process that will forward users to a page that requires authentication but I would like to hard code service account credentials in my PHP process to avoid the user from getting prompts for username/password when they are forwarded.
The pseudo code I have looks like this:

```
<?php

// User Login LDAP

$ldap = ldap_connect("example");
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $_POST['username'], $_POST['Password'])) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "not a success";
}

?>
```

I don’t expect any HTML as a user will hit the PHP file and should get auto forwarded to the page that requires credentials (in this case the page I am forwarding them to is an enterprise SharePoint site that requires Active Directory authentication).

Thank you in advance for any info/help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to post credentials to SharePoint's page using curl:

```
$params=['name'=>'John', 'surname'=>'Doe', 'age'=>36)
$defaults = array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://myremoteservice/',
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Maybe you'll need to encrypt the password before sending it to SharePoint.